# GCP K8 keeps adding a drop: NET_RAW by itself, how do I stop this?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to be able to use Ping from my container. However when I shell in and try I get

```
/bin/ping: Operation not permitted
```

I believe this is because Ping needs permissions to create raw packets. So I try and give my container this permission with this YAML in the deployment file

```
     securityContext:
        capabilities:
          add: ["NET_RAW"]
```

However when I check the YAML the has been applied through the GCP K8 GUI it appears as if its also had a drop applied for that permission.

```
 securityContext:
      capabilities:
        add:
        - NET_RAW
        drop:
        - NET_RAW
```

Can anyone explain why its doing that?

Comment: The below doc [1] mentions a limitation for GKE autopilot, can you confirm what is the GKE cluster type you are using? also you may have an admission controller doing this change (mutating).

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/sandbox-pods#capabilities

Comment: Why does your application need to send low-level ICMP packets?

Comment: @davidMaze there is a feature in the application to ping a user entered IP address

Comment: @reynaldo yes its autopilot

Comment: So this is working as intended, as per the below documentation.

If you use GKE Autopilot, Google Cloud prevents you from adding the NET_RAW permission to containers because of the security implications of this capability.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/sandbox-pods#capabilities